# force browser to open my applet in separate window

Tags: java, browser, applet

I need to open my applet in separate (not browser) window. I have searched but couldn't find anything interesting.

something similar is done here http://screencast-o-matic.com/screen_recorder

Comment: Once you have a nice frame, launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: @Koko - how did you solve it finally ? I also need a similar functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is possible. To open a new window from an applet you can refer this [DOC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is `JFrame/Frame` with transparent background. Take a look at interesting article - [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/).